# Calculate height and width of HTML content

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating a generic myWindow extending Ext.window.Window component.
here I need to support one feature to auto adjust height and widht of window.
This height and width will depend on height/width of HTML content inside the Window.
Is there any way in EXT JS or javascrip that can provide me height and width of html content.

Answer (score 0):

To get the height or width of an element in pixels (including padding and borders), use the [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight) and [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth) properties of the object. These values are readonly.

If you have set the style of the element, you can get the height and width (excluding padding and border) with the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) property:

```
var el = document.getElementById('elementId');
var width = el.style.width;
var height = el.style.height;
```

You can also set the height or width of the element this way.

```
el.style.width = 40 + 'px';
```

`'px'` can be changed to any valid unit, e.g. em.